# how to employ pipe to list with forecast object?

Tags: r, list, pipe, arima, forecast

it is known that a transformed version of the variable of interest may be better modelled with standard linear autoregressive integrated moving average (ARIMA) processes.   Of course, one may reverse the log transformation by applying the exponential function to the forecasts and thereby obtain a
forecast of the original variable. I can achieve the goal with base in R. Now i need get the same result in Shiny. i dont't know how to update the items of the list,fc. i think it is a solution with pipe. so how to employ pipe to list  with forecast object?

the R code in interactive environment is as follows:

```
library(forecast)
fc <- forecast(auto.arima(log(WWWusage) ) )
fc$x <-exp(fc$x)
fc$mean <-exp(fc$mean )
fc$fitted <-exp(fc$fitted)
fc$lower <-exp(fc$lower)
fc$upper <-exp(fc$upper)
fc$residuals <-exp(fc$residuals)
plot(fc)
```

the R code in shiny environment is as follows:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
plotOutput("out")
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
fc <- reactive(log(WWWusage) %>% auto.arima %>% forecast)
output$out <- renderPlot( plot(fc()))
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: You don't need to pipe your transformation just because it's in Shiny.  If your code works outside Shiny, it will work in Shiny.  Just return your plot object from the call to `renderPlot()`.  if you need more details, a MWE involving your Shiny code would be helpful.  Welcome to SO!

Comment: Limey, do you minding giving the codes?

Answer (score 1):

```
library(shiny)
library(forecast)

ui <- fluidPage(
        plotOutput("out")
      )

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  fc <- reactive({ 
          tmp <- forecast(auto.arima(log(WWWusage)))
          tmp$x <- exp(tmp$x)
          tmp$mean <- exp(tmp$mean )
          tmp$fitted <- exp(tmp$fitted)
          tmp$lower <- exp(tmp$lower)
          tmp$upper <- exp(tmp$upper)
          tmp$residuals <- exp(tmp$residuals)
          tmp
  })

  output$out <- renderPlot({
                  plot(fc())
                })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Based on the code you've given, I don't see any reason to make `fc` reactive.  But that may be the result of simplification as part of your MRE.  I note that `WWWusage` is undefined in your code - you'll have to amend my suggestion accordingly.